# Does Razor use SignalR by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor-server-side

So, I have been reworking an old WebForms site that our company has. In my initial efforts, I used Blazor which is SignalR based. This went well until I deployed the site to our servers that are behind a load balancer. After some research, I have come to the conclusion that unless the load balancer is configured to use sticky sessions, SignalR will not work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-3.1

And, unfortunately, our IT department refuses to do so.

So, I am reconsidering using an MVC project with Razor pages. My question is, will a project of this sort use SignalR under the hood as well, thus putting me in the same predicament?

If there are any other gotchas that anyone with more experience could point out, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: An ASP.NET MVC application does NOT have any hard dependency on SignalR, although SignalR is supported.

Comment: Thank you @DavidTansey. So if I start adding cshtml pages and razor components into the app, is SignalR going to somehow work its way into the project without me specifically going and getting the respective Nuget packages? That's what I'm concerned about. I didn't realize when I started with Blazor that SignalR was a part of it - and obviously given the environment I'm in I just want to make sure and steer clear of it.